# How were they able to track them easily?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-wars, the-last-jedi

**This might contain spoilers. Don't read if you haven't seen The Last Jedi yet.**

In the latest part of the franchise **Star Wars** - [The Last Jedi](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2527336/),

> The First Order was able to track the Resistance through lightspeed.

My question is: How exactly were they *(First Order)* able to do so? Has there been an indication of this in the past parts? Am I missing something?

Comment: My guess is they will make a new movie explaining it.

Comment: I hope so. And have you seen it yet? What a movie!

Comment: Better than I expected, it turns out Star Wars movies can be made without destroying another death star.

Comment: Haha, true. And the ending! Much better then expected!

Comment: Related - https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83741/how-did-dj-know-this

Comment: ...and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176357/how-was-the-first-order-tracking-the-resistance-in-the-last-jedi

Comment: In _The Last Jedi_, someone in the Resistance just describes the ability as "new tech".

Comment: Maybe someone from *Canto Bight* sold it to them... just saying.

Comment: When Jyn is looking through the Empire's code library in Rogue One she mentions one named "Hyperspace Tracking, Navigational Systems".

Comment: I think there were some rewrites and there was originally a traitor.  This would also explain how the hacker knows about the cloaked ships; Finn and Rose didn't even know about that.

Answer (score 3):

**I don't think they actually explain the technology fully.**

Rose refers to some concept called "Active Tracking", which Finn recognizes and immediately agrees that they're only being tracked by the lead ship. Clearly there's some existing technology that requires a **single** ship to be "the tracker". Perhaps it's an atmospheric technique (based on air movement) that has been adapted to work in space?

(Don't bother commenting about how there's no air in space, I get that. Maybe they discovered Star Trek's subspace and somehow that leaves a trail... or, maybe it's the force?)

Answer (score 1):

The 'Active Tracking' tech is discussed by Rose and Finn as the culprit, but it isn't really explained and seems to only serve as a mcguffin for their journey. Likely, this is the ace in the hole that General Hux was so smug about in his meeting with Snoke. It is worth noting that engine signature tracking is a common space sci-fi concept.